# How to manage devices that cannot access d-cache in ARM

Tags: arm, cortex-m, dma, stm32h7

I'm using an SPI device with DMA enabled in an STM32H7 SoC. The DMA periph. cannot access d-cache, so in order to make it work I have disabled d-cache entirely (for more info. about this, see [this explanation](https://community.st.com/s/article/FAQ-DMA-is-not-working-on-STM32H7-devices)). However, I would like to avoid disabling d-cache globally for a problem that only affects to a small region of memory.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421754/arm-cache-behaviour-is-clean-or-invalidate-the-correct-command-to-flush-cac) about the meaning of clean and invalidate cache operations, in the ARM domain. My understanding is that, by cleaning a cache area, you force it to be written in the actual memory. On the other hand, by invalidating a cache area, you force the actual memory to be cached. **Is this correct?**

My intention with this is to follow these steps to transmit something over SPI (with DMA):

1. Write the value you want on the buffer that DMA will read from.
2. *Clean* d-cache for that area to force it to go to actual memory, so DMA can see it.
3. Launch the operation: DMA will read the value from the area above and write it to the SPI's Tx buffer.
4. SPI reads data at the same time it writes, so there will be data in the SPI's Rx buffer, which will be read by DMA and then it will write it to the recv. buffer provided by the user. It could happen that an observer of such buffer can indeed access d-cache. The latter could not be updated with the new value received by SPI yet, so *invalidate* the recv. buffer area to force d-cache to get updated.

**Does the above make sense?**

### EDIT

Adding some more sources/examples of the problem I'm facing:

Example from the ST github: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeH7/issues/153

Post in ST forums answring and explaining the d-cache problem: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000m2fjHSAQ/confused-about-dma-and-cache-on-stm32-h7-devices

Here the interconnection between memory and DMA:
[image]
As you can see, DMA1 can access sram1, 2 and 3. I'm using sram2.

Here the cache attributes of sram2:

[image]

As you can see, it is *write back*,*write allocate*, but not *write through*. I'm not familiar with these attributes, so I read the definition from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-through-and-write-back-in-cache/). However, that article seems to talk about the CPU physical cache (L1, L2 etc.) I'm not sure if ARM i-cache and d-cache refer to this physical cache. In any case, I'm assuming the definition for *write through* and the other terms are valid for d-cache as well.

Comment: No it does not make sense to have a design that supports DMA require cleaning and invalidating.  If you find a design that requires that and there is no sane option, then discard that chip, blacklist that companies products for life, and find a better chip company to buy products from.  st is the top or one of the top cortex-m based chip companies so I doubt you will need to blacklist them.

Comment: I don't know about your device, but often there is a way to tell the CPU that a certain address range should be uncached, and then there is no need for manual clean or invalidate.  If you have an MMU, there are bits in the page tables to mark a page as "device" memory (instead of "normal"), which then makes it uncached. If not, there might still be some other way.

Comment: The fact that your table says **default** attributes suggests that there may be a way to change them.

Comment: "I'm not sure if ARM i-cache and d-cache refer to this physical cache."  Yes.  But it's a non-unified cache, so L1 may be split into L1i and L1d caches that handle instructions and data separately, and likewise for L2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated a bit more:

With regards to clean and invalidate memory question, the answer is yes: clean will force cache to be written in memory and invalidate will force memory to be cached.

With regards to the steps I proposed, again yes, it makes sense.

Here is a sequence of 4 videos that explain this exact situation (DMA and memory coherency). As can be seen, the 'software' solution (doesn't involve MPU) proposed by the videos (and other resources provided above) is exactly the sequence of steps I posted.

https://youtu.be/5xVKIGCPy2s

https://youtu.be/2q8IvCxSjaY

https://youtu.be/6IEtoG7m0jI

https://youtu.be/0DhYTqPCRiA

The other proposed solution is to configure the cortex-m7 MPU to change the attributes of a particular memory region to keep memory coherency.

This all apart from the easiest solution which is to globally disable d-cache, although, naturally, this is not desirable.

Answer (score -1):

I forget off-hand how the data cache works on the cortex-m7/armv7-m.  I want to remember it does not have an MMU and caching is based on address.  ARM and ST would be smart enough to know to put cached and non-cached access to sram from the processor core.

If you are wanting to send or receive data using DMA you do not go through the cache.

You linked a question from before which I had provided an answer.

Caches contain some amount of sram as we tend to see a spec for this many KBytes or this many MBytes, whatever.  But there are also tag rams and other infrastructure.  How does the cache know if there is a hit or a miss.  Not from the data, but from other bits of information.  Taken from the address of the transaction.  Some number of bits of that address are taken and compared to however many "ways" you have so there may be 8 ways for example so there are 8 small memories think of them as arrays of structures in C.  In that structure is some information is this cache line valid?  If valid what is the tag or bit of address that it is tied to, is it clean/dirty.

Clean or dirty meaning the overall caching infrastructure will be designed (kinda the whole point) to hold information in a faster sram (sram in mcus is very fast already so why a cache in the first place?), which means that write transactions, if they go through the cache (they should in some form) will get written to the cache, and then based on design/policy will get written out into system memory or at least get written on the memory side of the cache.  While the cache contains information that has been written that is not also in system memory (due to a write) that is dirty.  And when you clean the cache using ARM's term clean, or flush is another term, etc.  You go through all of the cache and look for items that are valid and dirty and you initiate writes to system memory to clean them.  This is how you force things out the cache into system memory for coherency reasons, if you have a need to do that.

Invalidate a cache simply means you go through the tag rams and you change the valid bit to indicate invalid for that cache line.  Basically that "loses" all information about that cache line it is now available to use. It will not result in any hits and it will not do a write to the system for a clean/flush.  The actual cache line in the cache memory does not have to be zeroed or put in any other state.  Technically just the valid/invalid bit or bits.

How things generally get into a cache are certainly from reads.  Depending on the design and settings if a read is cacheable then the cache will first look to see if it has a tag for that item and if it is valid, if so then it simply takes the information in the cache and returns it.  If there is a miss, that data does not have a copy in the cache, then it initiates one or more cache line reads from the system side.  So a single byte read can/will cause a larger, sometimes much larger, read to happen on the system side, the transaction is held until that (much larger) data (read) returns and then it is put in the cache and the item requested is returned to the processor.

Depending on the architecture and settings, writes may or may not create an entry in the cache, if a (cacheable) write happens and there are no hits in the cache then it may just go straight to the system side as a write of that size and shape.  As if the cache was not there.  If there is a cache hit then it will go into the cache, and the that/those cache lines are marked as dirty and then depending on the design, etc it may be written to system memory as a side effect of the write from the processor side, the processor will be freed to continue execution but the cache and other logic (write buffer) may continue to process this transaction moving this new data to the system side essentially cleaning/flushing automatically.  One normally does not expect this as it takes away performance that the cache was there to provide in the first place.

In any case if it is determined that a transaction has a miss and it is to be cached, then based on that tag, the ways have already been examined to determine if there was a hit.  One of the ways will be chosen to hold this new cache line.  How that is determined is based on design and in some cases programmable settings.  Hopefully if there are any that are invalid then it would go to one of those.  But round robin, randomizer, oldest first, etc are solutions you may see.  And if there is dirty data in that space then it has to get written out first, making room for the new information.  So, absolutely a single byte or single word read (since they have the same performance in a system like this) can require a cache flush of a cache line, then a read from the system and then the result is returned, more clock cycles than if the cache was not there.  Nature of the beast.  Caches are not perfect, with the right information and experience you can easily write code that makes the cache degrade the performance of the application.

Clean means if a cache line is valid and dirty then write it out to system memory and mark it as clean.

Invalidate means if the cache line is valid then mark it as valid. If it was valid and dirty that information is lost.

In your case you do not want to deal with cache at all for these transactions, the cache in question is in the arm core so nobody but the arm core has access to that cache, nobody else is behind the cache, they are all on the system end.

Taking a quick look at the ARM ARM for armv7-m they do use address space to determine write through and cached or not.  One then needs to look at the cortex-m7 TRM for further information and then, particularly in this case, since it is a chip thing not an arm thing anyway, the whole system.  The arm processor is just some bit of IP that st bought to glue into a chip with a bunch of other IP and IP of their own that is glued together.  Like the engine in the car, the engine manufacturer can't answer questions about the rear differential nor the transmission, that is the car company not the engine company.

1. arm knows what they are doing
2. st knows what they are doing
3. if a chip company makes a chip with dma but the only path between the processor and the memory shared with the dma engine is through the processor's cache when the cache is enabled, and clean/flush and invalidate of address ranges are constantly required to use that dma engine... then you need to immediately discard that chip, blacklist that company's products (if this product is that poorly designed then assume all of their products are), and find a better company to buy products from.

I can't imagine that is the case here, so

1. Initialize the peripheral, choosing to use DMA and configure the peripheral or dma engine or both (for each direction).
2. Start the peripheral (this might be part of 4)
3. write the tx data to the configured address space for dma
4. tell the peripheral to start the transfer
5. monitor for completion of transfer
6. read the received data from the configured address space for dma

That is generic but that is what you are looking for, caches are not involved.  For a part/family like this there should be countless examples including the (choose your name for the quality) one or more library solutions and examples that come from the chip vendor.  Look at how they others are using the part, compare that to the documentation, determine your risk level for their solution and use it or modify it or learn from it if nothing else.

I know that st products do not have an instruction cache they do their own thing, or at least that is what I remember (some trademarked name for a flash cache, on most of them you cannot turn it off).  Does that mean they have not implemented a data cache on the products either?  Possible.  Just because the architecture for an ip product has a feature (fpu, caches, ...) does not automatically mean that the chip vendor has enabled/implemented those.

Depending on the IP there are various ways to do that as some IP does not have a compile time option for the chip vendor to not compile in a feature.  If nothing else the chip vendor could simply stub out the cache memory interfaces and write a few lines of text in the docs that there is no cache, and you can write control registers and see things appear to enable that feature but it simply does not work.  One expects that arm provides compile time features, that are not in the public documentation we can see, but are available to the chip vendor in some form.

Sometimes when you buy the IP you are given a menu if you will like ordering a custom burger at a fancy burger shop, a list of checkboxes, mayo, mustard, pickle. ...  fpu, cache, 16 bit fetch, 32 bit fetch, one cycle multiply, x cycle multiply, divide, etc.  And the chip vendor then produces your custom burger.  Or some vendors you get the whole burger then you have to pick off the pickles and onions yourself.

Firstly, find out if this part even have a dcache?  Look between the arm arm, the arm trm and the documentation for the chip address spaces (as well as the countless examples) and determine what address space or whet settings, etc are needed to access portions of sram in a non-cached way.  If it has a data cache feature at all.

Comment: I have already make the SPI transfer work. I can see that, when I disable d-cache, it works. If I leave it enabled, it doesn't. With regards to the doubts about ARM/ST allowing the situation I described above to happen, I will quote part of the article, of the ST community, that I provided: [quote]The D-Cache can affect the functionality of DMA transfers, since it will hold the new data in the internal cache and don't write them to the SRAM memory. However the DMA controller loads the data from SRAM memory and not D-Cache.[/quote]

Comment: > [...]the only path between the processor and the memory shared with the dma engine is through the processors cache when the cache is enabled,[...] --> I think in this case it would be the opposite. The path between the processor and DMA in my case (STM32H7) is certain memory regions, such as sram2 (the one I'm using). The article I read states that writes from the processor to that area can be done to d-cache, therefore that data cannot be seen by DMA, since it will read directly from (in this case) sram2. That's my understanding.

Comment: I will edit my question to add a few more sources, examples etc.

Comment: you dont "write to dcache" unless you are using it as an sram.  each individual transaction is cacheable or not and the cache is enabled or not.  you write to an address.