# Data corruption issue with DMA operations on ARM Cortex-M7 (STM32F7) MCU

Tags: arm, cortex-m, cpu-cache, dma, stm32f7

I'm using an ARM Cortex-M7 microcontroller (specifically the STM32F767ZG) to communicate with external devices using 4 USARTs (configured as asynchronous transmitters/receivers, and using DMA to handle transfers). While testing the (bare metal) code, I noticed an issue with data corruption, possibly relating to the way ARM and/or the compiler deals with variables in cache and RAM. See the following test code:

```
volatile char buffer[3];

// USART & DMA initialization code
// ...

buffer[0] = 0x11;   //
buffer[1] = 0x22;   // Buffer initial values
buffer[2] = 0x33;   //

// Some other code
// ...

buffer[0] = 0xAA;   //
buffer[1] = 0xBB;   // Buffer updated values
buffer[2] = 0xCC;   //

// DMA stream starts here
// ...
```

Executing the above code, the data that comes out of the USART is the following:

```
0x11   (OLD value of buffer[0])
0x22   (OLD value of buffer[1])
0xCC   (NEW value of buffer[2])
```

I suspect this is relating to how ARM and/or the compiler deals with variables and their storage in cache and RAM. It seems that the contents of `buffer[]` take some time to reach the actual RAM, and, as a result, DMA picks up the *old* values. Note that, for the first two bytes, the USART Tx register is immediately free (due to USART's internal buffering), so the first two bytes (`buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]`) are read almost instantly by DMA. For the third byte, there is a 1-byte transmission delay (which, at 9600 bps is just over 1 ms), so in this case the MCU has plenty of time to update the RAM, hence the *new* value of `buffer[2]` is read by DMA.

This can be eliminated by simply adding a very small delay of just 1 microsecond *before* starting the DMA stream, like this:

```
...

Delay_us(1);

// DMA stream starts here
// ...
```

In this case, the USART sends the following (expected) data:

```
0xAA   (NEW value of buffer[0])
0xBB   (NEW value of buffer[1])
0xCC   (NEW value of buffer[2])
```

In fact, the above delay can be fine-tuned (in the nanosecond range), so that only the first byte is old, and the next two bytes are new (i.e., USART sends `0x11, 0xBB, 0xCC`).

My question is, how can I be absolutely sure that the actual RAM contents (to be read by DMA) reflect the buffer values I set in code? Adding a delay before initiating the DMA stream seems like a very crude and uncertain solution. Is there a definite way (a technique in C, or even an Assembly command) to flush the MCU cache and transfer its contents to RAM, so that there is no corruption in the buffer data in RAM?

Comment: You need to look into your cache configuration. You can invalidate cache and force it to write all the dirty lines back into RAM. Check out application note on cache of F7/H7 AN4839. Also, maybe you want a memory barrier to make sure all writes are, well, written at some point before getting DMA to work.

Comment: Many thanks @Ilya for the useful information. I've been Googling about this since I posted my question, and I found the same application note you've mentioned. Having worked mostly with small MCUs (like the 8-bit PIC18 series), I never came across such issues. The ARM Cortex-M7 is a beast of an MCU, with its own perks and caveats. I'm writing everything from scratch (bare metal code), so there are no ready-made cache manipulation functions to call, but I think AN4839 contains what I need. Still looking into it, and will post my results when I test things on Monday when I'm at the lab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer to my own question, after my investigation and lab experiments with the real h/w. It turns out that the DMA data corruption issue is indeed related to the MCU's Level 1 (L1) cache. The RAM region allocated to `buffer[]` by the compiler is, in general, *cacheable*, meaning that any read/write accesses from/to `buffer[]` go through L1 cache. However, as expected, DMA always directly accesses physical RAM, *not* cache, and this can lead to data corruption because the code and/or peripheral may actually be accessing *old* versions of the buffer data. This situation is called *loss of coherency*.

There are three standard approaches that can be employed to solve this:

1. Use a special instruction to *clean* the cache before initiating the DMA Tx transfer, forcing the MCU to write the cache contents to RAM (so that they can then be read by DMA). Similarly, use a special instruction to *invalidate* the cache before accessing the incoming data from the DMA Rx transfer, forcing the MCU to read the new data from RAM, instead of the old data in the cache.
2. Use the Memory Protection Unit (MPU) of the MCU to configure a specific region of RAM as *non-cacheable*. This ensures that all accesses to this region will always be done directly to RAM and will never go through the cache. I find the MPU approach to be the most elegant, as it guarantees coherency without the need to use `CleanDCache()` / `InvalidateDCache()` instructions before/after every DMA transaction. Alternatively, you can use the MPU to assign a *write-through* caching policy to the RAM region of interest. In this way, all cache writes are also immediately written to RAM, thus ensuring there is coherency between buffer data and DMA read accesses.
3. Allocate the DMA buffer inside a RAM region that is *already non-cacheable*. In the ARM Cortex-M7 MCU I'm using (STM32F767xx), there is a region of SRAM called DTCM-RAM, on TCM interface (Tightly Coupled Memory interface), mapped at address range `0x20000000 ~ 0x2001FFFF` (128 KB). This region is non-cacheable. Please note that there is no guarantee that DMA can access TCM memory in all MCUs, so this needs to be checked by reading the datasheet for the specific MCU of interest. In my case (STM32F767xx), DMA can access the 128 KB of DTCM-RAM, which is exactly what I need. This last method is the quickest solution, which can be applied by simply allocating `buffer[]` anywhere inside the non-cacheable region, as follows:

```
volatile char buffer[100] absolute 0x20000000;
```

Adding this single line in my code has completely solved all my DMA data corruption issues!

---

For more detailed information, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75494288/how-to-manage-devices-that-cannot-access-d-cache-in-arm?rq=2), and the links therein. Also, see the following resources by STMicroelectronics:

[PM0253 — STM32F7 Series and STM32H7 Series Cortex®-M7 processor programming manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/pm0253-stm32f7-series-and-stm32h7-series-cortexm7-processor-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

[AN4839 — Level 1 cache on STM32F7 Series and STM32H7 Series](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4839-level-1-cache-on-stm32f7-series-and-stm32h7-series-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

[AN4838 — Introduction to memory protection unit management on STM32 MCUs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4838-introduction-to-memory-protection-unit-management-on-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: Important additions: method 4: set caching policy to write-through, meaning all cache writes are also immediately written to RAM (increases read speed - reads use cache; as opposed to write-back cache policy, when writes are written to cache only, and are written out to RAM only when that cache line is invalidated/replaced with new content). Also, DMA doesn't necessarily have access to all RAM regions. Sometimes DMA has no access to tightly coupled memory. This needs to be verified on microcontroller basis. Check Bus Matrix of the MCU to see what all DMA controllers have or have no access to.

Comment: Many thanks @Ilya for the useful information, which I've already added to my answer. About write-through caching policy, I've included it in the 2nd approach, because it also uses the MPU.

Comment: I would just add to response that, if you're going to use CleanCache InvalidateCache (and it makes sanse if you're planning to double buffer and make your elaboration on the same buffer where you're collecting data), to take care and align your dma buffers with cache page size or you might lose data surraunding the buffers.